# Create file name with variable in it

Tags: python, variables

I'm very new to Python and still trying to figure things out. I have a large number of data files I need to concatenate but first I need to write the names of the files I want to merge into a text file so I can call on them in the next code. This will be for different years so I was to be able to set the variable 'years' to the year I want so it changes all the files in my code. This is what I have at the moment:

```
year = '07'

filenames = ['gdas1.jan"year".w1', 'gdas1.jan"year".w2','gdas1.jan"year".w3', 'gdas1.jan"year".w4', 'gdas1.jan"year".w5']
with open('D:/hysplitmergeoutput/hysplitnames"year"', 'w') as outfile:
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)

print hysplitnames"year"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the string  [`formatting functions`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *map* function this way :

```
year = "07"
filenames = ['gdas1.janYEAR.w1', 'gdas1.janYEAR.w2','gdas1.janYEAR.w3']
filenames_yeared = map(lambda x: x.replace("YEAR", year), filenames)
```

you will get this :

```
['gdas1.jan07.w1', 'gdas1.jan07.w2','gdas1.jan07.w3']
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting.
For example, if you want to substitute an integer you have to use the identifier %i like:

```
a = 1
b = "newstring%i" % a # print b --> "newstring1"
```

For your case:

```
for year in range(7,15,1):
   # year string
   if year<10: 
         year_str = "0%i" % year
   else: 
         year_str = "%i" % year


   # Build the array of filenames
   filenames = ["gdas1.jan%s.w" % year_str +  str(k) for k in range(1,6)]

   with open('D:/hysplitmergeoutput/hysplitnames%s' % year_str, 'w') as outfile:
        for fname in filenames:
            with open(fname) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)

   print hysplitnames+"%s" % year_str
```

The indentifier for string is %s and for floating numbers %.4f (with 4 digits).